# How to install TexMaker on Elementary OS

Tags: texmaker

I have installed Elementary OS and now I want to use TexMaker.
However when I go to the official website and go to download, the only options for linux are Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora, which one do I have to choose?

Comment: Have you googled it? Because there are tutorials on installing it that explicitly mention Elementary OS. Anyway, Elementary OS is a derivative of Ubuntu, so the Ubuntu package should work.

Comment: I would try `apt-get install texmaker` (or whatever way to install sowtware from the official repositories in Elementary OS is).